# Creating postfix template in Resharper for localization

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I localize my application using a separate library. How i can make a macro that allows you to automatically convert the string for example `$"My best string {code.property} with another {another.property}"` to

```
string.Format(
    LocalizationService.GetString("UserInputString", "AnotherUserInputString", "My best string {0} with another {1}"), 
    code.property, another.property)
```

Or another algorithm with simular result.

I can't figure out how to make a dynamically expandable postfix template. How i do it?